# Changed logo via config, changes not showing on frontend

Tags: magento-2.1, configuration, static-content

I've changed the logo & copyright tagline via `Content->Configuration->Edit->Header` etc., then flushed the cache, rebuilt the indexes, even recompiled DI, yet the new logo and copyright line aren't propagating through. Theme is the standard blank theme.

What did I miss?

Have tried:

- Rebuilding var/generation
- Rebuilding var/di
- Rebuilding pub/static
- Recompiling DI
- Rebuilding indexes
- Flushing all caches

Comment: please run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: maybe you have it set at store view level and you changed it at global level

Comment: I'm running single store mode, I can't see any store/global settings?

Comment: have you flush browser cache?

Comment: Flushed browser cache, tried different devices, different browsers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by disabling single store mode, and setting the logo/copyright at a different scope level.